# How to manage right click "Open in new tab" and "Open in new windows" in Linkbutton in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have LinkButton. It populates data and on the base of it, it redirects to the next page. Now the point is that when a user `Right Click --> Open in new tab` or `Open in new window` it opens blank windows.

There have ready many issue same like this but none of them work for me.

Here is my code:
aspx

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
                ID="Link_SignUp" 
                OnClick="Link_SignUp_Click">Signup Now!
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Click event

```
protected void Link_SignUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //populate data
    //make URL -- DotnetNuke
    string miUrl = base.EditUrl("", "", "portal_profile");
    //redirec to URL
    Response.Redirect(miUrl, true);
}
```

I have tried few solutions but none of them helped me.
I have tried to set Form property `target = _blank` and it worked but I have set it manually when on clientclick.

I want natural behavior.

1- When a user right clicks and selects "Open in new tab", it should open in a new tab.

2- When user right clicks and selects "Open in new window", it should open in a new window.

3- When user left clicks, it should open in the same page.

Comment: Why not load the URL when the page loads, and use a regular hyperlink control instead of a LinkButton?

Comment: Link button populates data and create Redirect URL. Thats why I didn't user Hyperlink. Please guide me.

Comment: Again - why not populate the data and create the correct URL *when the page loads* and assign it to the NavigateUrl of a HyperLink control? Why must you generate the correct URL when clicked? Why can't you do it beforehand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Create a hyperlink in your aspx view, instead of the link button.

On Page_Load, build up the relevant URL using the code you use in the Link_SignUp_Click event. Then, immediately after, you can assign the hyperlinks NavigateUrl property like so:

i.e.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string miUrl = base.EditUrl("", "", "portal_profile");
    HyperLinkID.NavigateUrl = miUrl;
}
```

Comment: No, don't use window.open. That doesn't respect the users wishes on where they want to open the link. It'd be much cleaner to just use a HyperLink and set NavigateUrl property. No JavaScript necessary.